# Laravel table join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5

I'm having difficulty properly joining tables in L5.

This joins my `articles` and users `tables`:

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
            ->join('users', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('articles.author', '=', 'users.id');

            })
            ->select('articles.id as id',
                     'articles.title as title',
                     'users.username as username',
                     'articles.created_at as created_at')
            ->latest('articles.created_at')
            ->get();
```

Everything seems to work, but it doesn't take into account `null` values for `articles.author`. I can't figure out the syntax to outer join correctly.

Also, please let me know if the rest of my query is written properly.

Comment: May be that helps you:
`->join('users', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('articles.author', '=', 'users.id')
                         ->where('articles.author', '!=', '');


            })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `leftJoin()` is the correct syntax for outer joining. This corrected my issue.